# Move and rename files in github

Tags: git, github, gitlab

I am using the Git Bash on Windows 10, *not* on the Linux command line.

I have files in a GitHub repo in a dir like such `subdir1/abc-hello.md`.  There are also other files in the directory.  I would like to move these files to another directory in the same repo and rename them by removing the "abc-" (`subdir2/hello.md`).  I know how to do this one by one using `git mv`, but I would like to do this in a bulk move while maintaining the file history.  I've read some other threads, but I'm new to bash scripting and can't get this to work.

Comment: You may have to do it in two steps? One commit for the directory rename, and one for the files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
cd subdir1
for file in abc-*.md; do
    newname=${file##abc-} # Remove "abc-"
    git mv $file ../subdir2/$newname
done
```

I.e. loop over files (adapt the list of files or the wildcard pattern), change every filename by removing 'abc-', move.